# Accessing rootState in Vuex getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

How do you access `rootState` in getters?

```
const getters = {
  getParams: rootState => {
    return rootState.route.params
  },
}
```

The above doesn't work. How is this done?

Comment: More context is needed. Are you in a module? If you are, then you'd need `getParams: (state, getters, rootState) => { ... }`.

Comment: All right. I added it.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If this getter is in a module `rootState` is the third arguments.

```
const getters = {
  getParams: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    return rootState.route.params
  }
}
```

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#getters for further information.

Comment: Strangely, `rootState.route` is empty for me in a simple getter just like this one?

Comment: If your file is typescript, write (state, getters, rootState: any) in order to have access to rootState