# Setting a variable on vuex module from another module getters Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

The application is build with Nuxt.js. I am trying to initiate a variable on vuex module which is used to call axios on each actions.

**store/program.js**

```
let program_url = 'programs/';

export const actions = {
  async programList({commit}) {
    await this.$axios.$get(program_url).then((response) => {
      commit("ALL_PROGRAMS", response);
    });
  },
```

The problem I am facing is that this variable depends on a state variable in another vuex module. What I am trying to build here is on **store/program.js** I want to initiate a variable called `program = <dynamic_id_from_another_vuex_module>/program`

The other store file is **store/university.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  settings: [],
  id: null
});

export const getters = {
  getId(state) {
    return state.id;
  }
};
```

So How do I do something like below inside my **store/program.js** ?

```
let program = store.getters['university/getId'] + 'program';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing rootState in Vuex getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171276/accessing-rootstate-in-vuex-getter)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `rootState` in your getters like following...

```
getId(state, getters, rootState) {
    return rootState.university.id  // Here I assume university is the another  module
}
```

That's it :)

Comment: But that is to access another vuex getters inside my getters. What if I want to use it outside my getters. Like what if I want to define e variable like below?

`let program = store.getters['university/getId']`

Comment: If you want to access getters from another module of your vuex then simply getters.YourGettersName from your current getters. And don't forget to write like that `getId(state, getters, rootState)`